# MySQL EXISTS() errors

Tags: mysql, exists

I am getting errors from mysql when using the EXISTS function.  I would go the ON DUPLICATE KEY route but the 'str' field has to be a TEXT type.

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `locale_display_string` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `str` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `date` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
TYPE=MyISAM;
```

Here is the query I am trying to run:

```
INSERT INTO `locale_display_string` (str, date) VALUES ('test', '1368204427') 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `locale_display_string` WHERE str='test');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think MySQL INSERT Syntax supports WHERE clause

Comment: I can't even do 'SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM locale_display_string);'

Comment: @Sudz it just gives me the usual 'theres an error somewhere near <the whole query>'

Comment: INSERT doesn't allow WHERE in the syntax. dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html @Explosion Pills answer is one way to solve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VALUES is not compatible ... use `SELECT`.

```
INSERT INTO `locale_display_string` (str, date)
SELECT 'test', '1368204427'
FROM `locale_display_string`
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT TRUE FROM `locale_display_string` WHERE str='test')
LIMIT 1
```